# code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) error while creating minidcos cluster

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I'm trying to create mini DCOS cluster in Mac OS.

My minidcos version is -

```
    $ minidcos --version
    minidcos, version 2019.02.17.1
```

When I run the below command to create the cluster I get the error -

```
    $ minidcos vagrant create ./dcos_generate_config.sh --agents 0
    Bringing machine 'dcos-e2e-f2c21a1a-a220-4a33-a528-493a11f16440-master-0' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    Bringing machine 'dcos-e2e-f2c21a1a-a220-4a33-a528-493a11f16440-public-agent-0' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> dcos-e2e-f2c21a1a-a220-4a33-a528-493a11f16440-master-0: Importing base box 'mesosphere/dcos-centos-virtualbox'...
    Progress: 90%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
    for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

    Command: ["import", "/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.vagrant.d/boxes/mesosphere-VAGRANTSLASH-dcos-centos-virtualbox/0.9.2/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "packer-virtualbox-iso-1500059987_1551037690830_88506", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "8", "--disk", "/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/VirtualBox VMs/packer-virtualbox-iso-1500059987_1551037690830_88506/packer-virtualbox-iso-1500059987-disk001.vmdk"]

    Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
    Interpreting /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.vagrant.d/boxes/mesosphere-VAGRANTSLASH-dcos-centos-virtualbox/0.9.2/virtualbox/box.ovf...
    OK.
    0%...
    Progress state: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND
    VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
    VBoxManage: error: Error opening '/Users/rajkumar.natarajan/.vagrant.d/boxes/mesosphere-VAGRANTSLASH-dcos-centos-virtualbox/0.9.2/virtualbox/packer-virtualbox-iso-1500059987-disk001.vmdk' for reading (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
    VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg *)" at line 886 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp

    Error creating cluster.
    Full error:
    Command '['/usr/local/bin/vagrant', 'up']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Try "minidcos vagrant doctor" for troubleshooting help.
```

I'm not sure what is the root cause of this error?

Comment: Have you tried running minidcos with Docker in a virtual Machine in VirtualBox? It does not depend VirtualBox commands.

Comment: @Alwinius - Yes. That works. But I want to know why vagrant flavor is not working.